# How do I call a 6-digit Australian phone number with a US-based mobile phone?

Tags: cellphones, phone-networks

This may not exactly fit the context of this site, but I think it's worth a shot, and the answer may be useful within the context of the site.

I am attempting to call the Australian phone number listed as `131542` on the [Kia of Australia Contact Us](https://www.kia.com/au/util/contact-us.html) page from my US-based mobile phone. Though, even after reading the Wikipedia page on [Telephone Numbers in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia) I can not seem to get it correct. My best guess is to use the "International Access" code of `1100` along with the country code `61` prepended (totaling `61-1100-1315421`). Though I've had no luck with that or any other seemingly esoteric collection of codes and the listed number.

**How can I dial a 6-digit Australian phone number from a US based mobile phone?** I have Verizon Wireless for my mobile carrier.

---

This may be useful to other travelers trying to contact Australian companies, hotels, etc. And for those interested, Kia of Australia sells a cargo roof rack for my car that Kia of America does not recognize or sell. I am trying to get more information on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to shopping, not travel.  (And not shopping for something travel-related.)

Comment: @WGroleau, on the other hand, knowing how to call out of a country can be very handy for travellers.  I remember being sent to England on a business trip.  After I arrived I wanted to phone my wife and had a lot of trouble doing so.  It was a small hotel, with no staff in the evening or at night.  The room phone had good instructions: "9" to get an outside line, "00" to make an international call, country code, and finally the phone number.  But it took me a long time to figure out that for Canada, the "country code" was the "1" that I normally use for long distance calls.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm not sure why you're putting scare quotes around "country code", as if to suggest that that's not really what it is. And, as your comment demonstrates, you could easily find out how to call out of the country because clear instructions were provided. The only reason you had difficulty is that you neglected to find out what your country code was before leaving.

Comment: @WGroleau Shopping? Where on earth did you get that? Calling internationally is most certainly something an international traveler is likely to need to do at some point.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I've no idea why I quoted "country code" (perhaps because it was 2am when I did it?).  "_you neglected to find out what your country code was before leaving_".  Exactly.  Maybe I had that Ugly American or Snooty British attitude that country codes are for calling _foreign_ countries, and I wanted to call home, not a foreign country.  But in general, I wonder how many other people, especially those in North America, know their own country code.  If nothing else, this item is a reminder to its readers to retain that information.

Comment: @Kevin, OP said the purpose was to buy something from Australia.  Not leaving USA wasn't stated, but implied.  Anyway, it's not up to me, but up to however many other reviewers vote.

Comment: So his most immediate use might not be travel directly. It's still exceedingly useful knowledge for traveling. Edit the reference to shopping out if it bothers you.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm not really seeing why describing your own mistake requires you to insult Americans or British people. Country codes are for calling internationally, just like area codes are for calling between different areas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I wasn't insulting either Americans or British, I was acknowledging that I myself was guilty of having the attitudes represented by the [Ugly American (pejorative) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_(pejorative)) and "Snooty British" stereotypes.  My comment should be no more insulting than "Downton Abbey" is insulting.

Comment: I'm probably too late but before you go calling Australia from your standard VZ wireless account, look into cheaper VOIP alternatives.  Google voice comes to mind and only charges $0.01/min to call an Australian landline.

Comment: Thinking it through, It's obvious that _prepending_ the country code _before_ the international access code is backwards.  The whole point of the international access code is to tell the switching equipment "here comes a country code [followed by a number within that country]".  To do that after dialing the country code would be pointless.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Where are you getting the "**1100**" code from?  That might be your problem.

USA, Canada, and other countries in country code "1" use "**011**" as the [international dialing prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes).

You would normally dial:

- "**011**" - "I want to call a different country."
- "61" - Australia country code.
- "131 542" - The number in Australia.

To call you, people in Australia would dial:

- "**0011**" - "I want to call a different country."
- "1" - North America country code
- "213" - Area code for Los Angeles
- "555" - Exchange
- "2368" - Number

See [International Calling Codes - Nations Online Project](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/international-calling-codes.htm)

EDIT:

- "J..." points out that this isn't a normal local Australian number: it is only 6 digits.
- [Telephone numbers in Australia - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia#Local_Rate_and_FreeCall_numbers_(13,_180)) says that numbers like this (beginning with "13") are special numbers that automatically reverse the long-distance charges, equivalent to North America's "+1-800" numbers.
- These toll free numbers can be restricted for use within certain areas (e.g. within Australia only).
- So, even when the international dialing prefix *is* correct, it might *still* be impossible for the call to go through.

AND:

- "Eric" says "If you hold 0 on most mobile phones when entering a phone number, it will enter the ‘+’ symbol, which avoids the need to enter locale specific prefixes to country codes.".
- Always storing numbers on one's phone with a leading "+" will allow them to be easily called regardless of which country one is.
  The conversion of "+" to the local international access code is similar to how "211" automatically converts to the local emergency number in most countries (e.g. "911" in North America and "999" in Britain).

Comment: If you hold 0 on most mobile phones when entering a phone number, it will enter the ‘+’ symbol, which avoids the need to enter locale specific prefixes to country codes.

Comment: There are countries using 011 and 0011? Here we simply use 00 (or +) to call our international neighbours. So, 0032 (or +32) for Belgium. Do you leave the 0 away from area codes as well, or do your area codes not have a 0 in front at all?

Comment: @Mast Yes (to your first question).  That is *why* the standard prefix is '+' - to stand in for all the different national prefixes.

Comment: @Mast, "00" is the most common ICC, but there are many others.  Look at the ICC link above.  It shows 20 different codes, with 169 places using "00", 25 using "011", 9 using "810", and so on.

Comment: @Mast: Re "do your area codes not have a 0 in front at all?" - The North American Numbering Plan uses a clever hack. If you are dialing long-distance within the NANP, you ([usually](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061127-14/?p=28903)) prefix the area code with a **1** to indicate long-distance. If you are dialing an NANP number internationally, you dial **+1** (NANP's country code), and then the area code. So the number starts with a 1 either way. Regardless, the three-digit area code itself *must not* begin with zero, because dialing zero gets you operator assistance under NANP.

Comment: 2/2 The net effect of all that is that you can just whack a "+" in front of a long-distance NANP number to convert it into an international number, which is very neat.

Comment: @Mast the first digit of a north american area code is always 2 through 9.

Comment: @hobbs, and until recently, the three-digit area codes always had "0" or "1" as their second digit, while the three-digit exchange codes never had "0" or "1" as their first or second digit.  Now we have to dial all ten digits, but before we could omit the area code if it was the same as ours without any the ambiguity.  And when I was *very* young, in many places one could even omit the exchange if it was the same as the calling number's and simply dial four digits to call someone in the very local area.

Comment: @RayButterworth and the second and third numbers are never both 1, because the x11 numbers are special three-digit numbers for local services, the most well known of which is the emergency number 911.

Comment: @AndrewRay, and "112" is the emergency number on most modern mobile phones, and should work almost anywhere in the world. For instance, in North America it automatically redirects to "911". (I don't know about elsewhere, but on mobile phones it works in Canada even without a SIM card.)

Comment: @RayButterworth But 112 is of course not one of the x11 numbers. It's disallowed as an area code or exchange code because it starts with 1, and can't be a long-distance 1 followed by an area code 12x because that would also be a disallowed area code starting with 1. So it is in fact just a happy coincidence that mobile phones can reroute that number in the US because it just happens to be the case that no valid NANP number can start with that sequence.

Comment: The other n11 numbers in the US are 211 Community Information, 311 Police Non-Emergency, 411 Directory Assistance, 511 Traffic and Transportation, 611 Repair services, 711 Telecommunications Relay Service, and 811 "Access to One Call Services to Protect Pipeline and Utilities from Excavation Damage" (also called "Dig Safe" or "Call before you Dig").

Comment: Another good list of International Direct Dial (IDD) prefix numbers is https://www.idd.com.au/international-dialling-codes.php

Answer (score 26):

To dial a number in another country, you first dial the international access code for your country, then the code for the country you're calling, then the actual phone number, usually omitting the first zero if any.
You can replace the international access code with a **+** on mobile phones.

The [international access code for the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes) is **011**.
The [country code for Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Zone_6:_Southeast_Asia_and_Oceania) is **61**.

So that would make it **011 61 131542** or **+61 131542** for your example.

However, that may not work. The Australian equivalents of the US 1-800 numbers are [13 numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Australia#Local_Rate_and_FreeCall_numbers_(13,_180)) (as well as 1300 and 1800), as is the number you want to call. They are charged at a local rate to the caller. The downside is that they're often not available from abroad, likely because the owner is charged the actual cost of calling the number.

---

However, Kia has [a dealer locator](https://www.kia.com/au/shopping-tools/find-a-dealer.html) that shows phone numbers for those dealers. Those seem to be regular phone numbers that *are* callable from outside Australia. Pick one of those and call them, either doing your business with them directly, or asking them for a number to call from abroad.

Alternatively, you can call Kia USA and ask them for a number to call Kia AU on.

Comment: Is 011 actually used anymore? I can dial any international number from my mobile phone in the US and it will work.

Comment: @JonathanReez phones and mobile providers make dialing more convenient by hiding these details from you but they're not gone, just hidden. Also, odds are that you can only dial SOME international numbers and have them work.

Comment: @JonathanReez Only on landlines and VoIP lines.

Comment: +1 for addressing the fact that this is a 13 number and that there are special caveats for calling these virtual numbers which do not apply to regular landline or mobile numbers.

Comment: You can use a + on any phone that supports it.

Answer (score 26):

13xxxx is a "magic" number.

For instance, calling 131 888 will ring the nearest Domino's Pizza (to your location in Australia).  Your number will presumably reach the nearest Kia dealer.

From Wikipedia:

> 13 xx xx, 1300 xxx xxx and 1800 xxx xxx numbers can provide source-based routing, used by organisations such as pizza chains that advertise one number nationwide that connects customers to their nearest store.

These magic numbers do not work internationally, for obvious reasons.

Comment: It's like 112 (emergency services) but for normal companies! Pretty cool idea.

Comment: And of particular use for travellers, 131008 will connect you to the local taxi booking line anywhere in Australia.

Comment: @caf could you please put that into a self answered question? That's incredibly useful info.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to route an international call from the US to the closest Australian Domino's Pizza. However, if the caller with an American phone _is_ in Australia, I would expect they worked (when providing all the required country code prefixes).

Comment: But they do work internationally.  I literally just called the Kia one from New Zealand.

Comment: @MarkMayo You should have ordered unbaked pizza from Domino's instead of calling Kia; at least in North America it's delivered in 30 minutes or it's free.

Answer (score 11):

They [aren't accessible from every country](https://www.1300numbersaustralia.com.au/what-you-need-to-know-about-calling-a-1300-number-from-overseas), but from the US it should be.

[International dial-out code] + (61) + your inbound number should do the trick.

So in this case, 1100, if that's your dial out code, 61, then 131542.

Note: + usually means international too, replacing 00, so in my experience I just dial +61 131542.

I'm not sure about the dial out code, you'll need to see if you need that (I don't from NZ), but as I'm in NZ at present I just tried, and dialling +61131542 worked for me.

Comment: This is actually one of the first numbers I tried. Ill try looking around for what my dial out code may be. Though Ive only ever heard of one in terms of a business phone line, like from within a large corporate building phone network.

Comment: @KDecker: [Dial out codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes).  But I think it's extremely common on mobile phones that the `+` key automatically dials your dial out code, whatever it happens to be for your phone, so you should not need to actually look it up.

Answer (score 7):

**Telephoning Kia from International may not be possible** because of their short number - it may be a special number like a US 1-800 that doesn't work internationally.

Australian landline telephone numbers **are** 8 digit.

> Australia uses eight digit local phone numbers preceded by a two digit STD area code.
> [Source](https://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/telephone-country-and-area-codes)

So the quoted 6 digit phone number is something odd.

> The Australian country code is 61. When calling from outside Australia, leave out the leading '0' from the STD area code or from the mobile telephone number.
>
> Example: Fixed line example calling Canberra from outside Australia: +61 2 (local eight digit number)
>
> The Area Code for NSW is probably 02 but some areas may use the 08 and 03 area codes instead.
> [Source](https://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/telephone-country-and-area-codes)

---

Alternatives, why not use a simple local telephone?  Payphones still exist, or your accommodation should have some kind of telephone.  You could also purchase a "prepay" or "pay as you go" sim and see if it works in your phone.   Or purchase a cheap cellphone for the time you're in Australia, and gift it to someone else before you leave.

Comment: It is very easy to dial a six digit 13 number from OS.  These are often critical services.

Answer (score 3):

One approach that is [generally useful for calling toll-free numbers](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa10613/how-do-i-make-a-call-in-skype) (from outside the country they're intended to be used in) but, unfortunately, fails in the case of Australian toll-free numbers is to use Skype to phone (you need to have a credit to use the service, about $10 USD is the minimum):

> Yes, use the dial pad to enter toll free numbers on Skype. The following countries and number ranges are supported and are free of charge to all users:
>
> France: +33 800, +33 805, +33 809
>
> Poland: +48 800
>
> UK: +44 500, +44 800, +44 808
>
> USA: +1 800, +1 866, +1 877, +1 888
>
> Taiwan: +886 80

That also allows you to call regular phones from a cell phone using local cellular data or WiFi access points, which I find very useful. Again, it's not free, but quite cheap (2-3 cents/minute), in my experience.

Comment: You *can* call 13-numbers via Skype, it's just rather expensive: [AUD](https://i.imgur.com/kyAZG7K.png), [USD](https://i.imgur.com/jdcSSfs.png). See rates at the bottom of https://www.skype.com/en/international-calls/Australia. Also, 13-numbers aren't toll-free - those are 1800-numbers here.

Answer (score 3):

It is not enough to use 61 as the country code.

You must also use an area code.

So +61 2 132221 for CBA IVR/VRU

Be aware that 13 numbers are not always the same across all area codes or even regions that share the area codes. Annoying if it is used in a jingle and then does not work.

If you are calling Centrelink (!) be very sure to tell them where they might think you normally live, their systems may make assumptions and not find your records, the same as calling them from interstate.

This is a big problem between SA and WA as they are both '08' or +618.  You will likely get the SA number. You cannot dial 1194 in this way, and inside Australia 081194 is the time in Adelaide, not Perth.

Be also aware that most companies using 13 numbers have an alias landline number specifically for calling from overseas.

Answer (score 2):

SQB covered it very well.. Six digit 13 numbers are generally for use only within Australia because the owner of the number might be charged for its use. That is also why there are significantly higher call rates for those numbers on Skype if you can get them to work.

To call Australia landline numbers use either 001161 or +61 prior to the Australian number. Landlines will have a two digit area code beginning with zero (0) and mobile numbers all begin with 04. In both cases drop the zero. For example landline 02-12345678 becomes +61212345678 and mobile 0412345678 becomes +61412345678.